# Count down timer in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am new to android.I am having an app which can be used for exam management.Users can insert the date of every subjects and the app will provide time(in hours) for each subject.There is countdown timer which will start from the time allocated for each subject(for eg,48 hours) and should go to zero.when it hits zero an alarm should be played showing that time allocated for that subject has got over.this is my code.

```
public class Alarmpage extends Activity{

    TextView hourshow,minshow,secshow;
    SQLiteDatabase database_read;
    sampleDatabase samp;
    Cursor cur;
    Handler handler;
    int initStart;
    Runnable updater;
    int  t;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);
        hourshow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hr);
        samp=new sampleDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        database_read=samp.getReadableDatabase();
        minshow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.min);
        secshow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sec);
        cur=database_read.query(sampleDatabase.TABLE_SEC, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        if(cur.moveToFirst())
            {
                 t=cur.getInt(3);
                 Log.e("time", String.valueOf(t));
            }
        handler=new Handler();
        initStart = (int) SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        Log.e("init", String.valueOf(initStart));
        updater = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 int sec,minute,hour;
                  int diff = t*60*60;
                Log.e("time in sec", String.valueOf(diff));
                System.out.println(diff);


                /*if(diff>=1)
                {
                     hour= diff/3600;
                }
                else {hour = 00; }
                hourshow.setText(String.valueOf(hour));
                Log.e("diff after hour", String.valueOf(diff));
                Log.e("hour", String.valueOf(hour));
                minute = (diff % 3600) / 60;


                minshow.setText(":"+String.valueOf(minute));
                    sec= (diff % 60);

                secshow.setText(":"+String.valueOf(sec));*/
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    sec =  (int) (diff%60);
                } else {
                    sec=00;
                }
                secshow.setText(":"+String.valueOf(sec));
                diff = diff/60;
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    minute =  (int) (diff%60);
                } else {
                    minute=00;
                }
                minshow.setText(":"+String.valueOf(minute));
                diff = diff/60;
                if (diff >= 1) {
                    hour =  (int) (diff%24);
                } else {hour = 00; }
                hourshow.setText(String.valueOf(hour));
                t=(t*60*60)-1;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.post(updater);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
    }
}
```

but its showing some values.but they are not correct.kindly help me.I dont understand error in this code.Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you use a Timer? http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12

Comment: i think you should use [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) for exam management.

Comment: @noxius I am little awared about Timers in android.Can you help me plz.

Comment: I am little awared about CountDownTimer in android.Can you help me plz.

Comment: `t=(t*60*60)-1;` is probably not what you want.

Comment: @njzk2 that is for changing the value of t,which is in hour(i am converting hours into seconds) form

Comment: yes, but no. each time you run your runnable, t is basically multiplied by almost 3600. you should only be decreasing it, i think

Comment: check out the example:  http://steve.odyfamily.com/?p=12